# How to 'subset' a named vector in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have this named vector in R:

```
foo=vector()
foo['a']=1
foo['b']=2
foo['c']=3
```

How do I most cleanly make another named vector with only elements 'a' and 'c'?

If this were a data frame with a column "name" and a column "value" I could use

```
subset(df, name %in% c('a', 'b'))
```

which is nice because subset can evaluate any boolean expression, so it is quite flexible.

Comment: You can still use `subset(foo, names(foo) %in% c('a', 'c'))` but @AndreyShabalin answer is cleaner

Comment: Additionally take a look at this question: [In R, why is `[` better than `subset`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this:

```
foo[c('a','b')]
```

Comment: Is there a way to negate this syntax? It seems that you can write `foo[-1]` but not `foo[-"a"]`.

Comment: `foo[!(names(foo) %in% c('a','b'))]`

Answer (score 3):

As a sidenote, avoid 'growing' structures in R. Your example can be write like this also:

```
foo = c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
```

To subset just do like Andrey's answer:

```
foo[c('a','b')]
```

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.