# tallying up the number of values in data frame in R from multiple columns

Tags: r, counting

I would like to be able to create a function that would be able to tally up the number of values in columns L2, L3, and L4 that are greater than 0 as a function of some name.

```
Name    L1     L2     L3    L4
Carl    1       1     0     2
Carl    0       1     4     1 
Joe     3       0     3     1
Joe     2       2     1     0
```

For example,  someFunction(Carl) = 5
and someFunction(Joe) = 4

I do not want to sum up the values, for example someFunction(Joe) = 7 is incorrect.
I hope this makes sense, I am pretty stuck on this. Thanks!

Comment: Will this do it? `sum(df[df$Name == 'Carl', -c(1, 2)] > 0)`

Comment: Try also `tapply(rowSums(df[,3:5]>0),df$Name,sum)`.

Comment: @Gopala thank you, but i am getting this error in return:   only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

Comment: I don't know what the column types are in your data. `str(df)` should tell you.

Comment: @nicola +1. That is a good solution for getting result on all names. I was focusing on one since a function(name) was mentioned.

Comment: @nicola that works for getting a result on all the names. Do you know how I would get one result for just one name? for example, function(Joe) = 4

Comment: My code above gives for one name ('Carl' in that case). You can easily substitute Joe like this `sum(df[df$Name == 'Joe', -c(1, 2)] > 0)`. Also, easy to wrap in a function.

Comment: @Gopala Thank you for your suggestions, however, I am still getting the same error: only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

Comment: @nicoles solution returns a named vector, so you can subset by the name you require

Comment: @user127649 thanks, do you know how I go about doing this? if you cant tell, im very very new to R :)

Comment: @count below posted an answer with a function wrapper. Take a look at that. The actual piece of code is very similar to what I gave above.

Comment: I do, but as it looks like homework, or that you're just waiting for someone else to do all the work, I thing the hint should point you in the right direction - google is your friend

Comment: @user127649 nope, not homework. Just a biologist trying to figure out R. Im pretty confused with the syntax...there are so many ways to execute one thing!

Comment: See if just sticking `['Carl']` on the end of @nicola's solution works. See [link text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794650/how-to-subset-a-named-vector-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you want to have a function:

```
give_count <- function(dat,name) {
    sum(dat[dat$Name == name,3:ncol(dat)]!=0)
    }
give_count(data,"Joe")
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I use this on my data frame, I am getting an answer back as NA.

Comment: Is your `data.frame` named `data`? If not, Change the first Argument in the function according to the Name of your `data.frame`. If you have more than 5 columns in your data and only want three columns evaluated Change the `ncol(dat)` in the function to `5`.

Comment: thank you. for some reason i still am getting NA. I actually have 14 total columns, but i only want to evaluate columns 6:13.

Comment: Have you checked with `str(your.data.frame)`whether we are talking about integer/numeric values?

Comment: columns 1:2 are integer, columns 3:5 are "Factor", and columns 6:13 are integers. Column 14 is logical

Comment: Did you alter the function accordingly? `sum(dat[dat$Name == name,6:13]!=0)`

Comment: This seemed to work! However, it is giving me a result that is larger than I think it should be... I also have negative numbers in these columns. Does the  !=0 part of your code pick up the values that arent equal to 0? I need only the values that are > 0

Comment: Yup, negative values will be counted. Just cahnge the `!=` to `>` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Name', specify the columns of interest, in `.SDcols`, `unlist` the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), check whether it is greater than 0, and get the `sum` of the logical vector.  This is assigned (`:=`) to create the 'N' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, N := sum(unlist(.SD)>0), Name, .SDcols = L2:L4]
df1
#   Name L1 L2 L3 L4 N
#1: Carl  1  1  0  2 5
#2: Carl  0  1  4  1 5
#3:  Joe  3  0  3  1 4
#4:  Joe  2  2  1  0 4
```

---

Or another option is

```
setDT(df1)[,  N := sum(unlist(lapply(.SD, `>`, 0))), Name, .SDcols = L2:L4]
```

---

Or we can use `rowsum/rowSums` combination in `base R`

```
rowSums(rowsum(+(df1[3:5]>0), df1$Name))
#   Carl  Joe 
#   5    4
```

---

If we need only to do this for a particular 'Name'

```
setDT(df1)[Name == "Carl"][, sum(unlist(.SD) > 0), .SDcols = L2:L4]
```

#### Update

If we need a summarised output, do not assign (`:=`)

```
setDT(df1)[, .(N = sum(unlist(.SD)>0)), Name, .SDcols = L2:L4]
#   Name N
#1: Carl 5
#2:  Joe 4
```

Comment: is setDT a function in R? Sorry, Im very new!

Comment: @Amanda It is a function in `data.table` to convert 'data.frame' to 'data.table'.  There is a `setDF` function which does the opposite

Comment: I like your rowSums suggestion a lot. This gives me the count for all the names, however, do you know how I would get one result for one name? I would like to create a function, such that function(Joe) = 4

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage usage of the `tidyverse` style of coding. If you use `dplyr` and `reshape2` packages, the code is elegant and easy to read:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
df1 %>% 
  select(-L1) %>% 
  melt(id=1,na.rm=T) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  transmute(flag=value>0) %>% 
  summarize(sum(flag))


# A tibble: 2 × 2
    Name `sum(flag)`
  <fctr>       <int>
1   Carl           5
2    Joe           4
```